# C# - Change value of all rows of a specific colum of a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I have a DataTable. What I want to do is change the value of all rows of the Colum "X" of the DataTable.

For example:

if row value is "TRUE" then change it into "Yes"
else change it into "No"

Comment: Tried anything at all so far?

Comment: not too complicated although you might run into data type issues if column "X" is a boolean/bit field...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe you could try this

```
int columnNumber = 5; //Put your column X number here
for(int i = 0; i < yourDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (yourDataTable.Rows[i][columnNumber].ToString() == "TRUE")
    { yourDataTable.Rows[i][columnNumber] = "Yes"; }
    else
    { yourDataTable.Rows[i][columnNumber] = "No"; }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 6):

A simple loop:

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    string oldX = row.Field<String>("X");
    string newX = "TRUE".Equals(oldX, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "Yes" : "No";
    row.SetField("X", newX);
}
```

`StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` enables case insensitive comparison, if you don't want "Equals" to be "Yes" simply use the `==` operator.

Comment: +1 for suggesting StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase

Comment: what if row.Field<String>("X") is not a String but a Boolean (ie column X is a bit/boolean)? Would setting the field to "Yes" or "No" cause an issue?

Comment: @Ric: The `Field` extension method is strongly typed which also suppiort nullable types, that's why i have used it. It will raise an exception if the type is not a string. If it's a boolean column you have to use `Field<bool>("X")`. But then you need to use a different column for the string representation or change the database query to return a varchar instead of bool(f.e. `SELECT CASE WHEN X=1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS X`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was getting at. If column X is a boolean and is being casted to String, then InvalidCastException will be thrown. I was going to point out that maybe a new column should be brought into the result set or altering the query as you mentioned. Nice one!